# C# EWS Save all Email Found in Inbox Into an Item List

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

My current code accesses all unread email in `Inbox`. However, as this is a method which will return the list of emails for further processing for each email.

I am unsure of how to group the emails found into a list or table.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
private static GetNewEmailInInbox(ExchangeService service, int batch, string autoDiscoverURL)
{
    if (service != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accessing system account mailbox...");

        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, -1, 0, 0);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Add(ts);
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(autoDiscoverURL);
        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

        FindItemsResults<Item> emailItemList;
        ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
        int inboxCount = 1;
        do
        {
            emailItemList = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
            foreach (var emailItem in emailItemList.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(inboxCount + ". " + emailItem.Subject);
                inboxCount++;

                //add this email to an allEmailList
            }

            if (!emailItemList.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
                break;
        }
        while (emailItemList.MoreAvailable);
    }
return allEmailList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the emails using an [IList Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
IList<T> allEmailList = new List<T>();

FindItemsResults<Item> emailItemList = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
foreach (var emailItem in emailItemList.Items.OfType<T>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(inboxCount + ". " + emailItem.Subject);
    inboxCount++;

    //add this email to an allEmailList
    allEmailList.Add(emailItem);
}
```